# How to uninstall complete NVM in macOS

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have already installed Node.js v16 and Node Version Manager (NVM) on my mac. It's caused some conflict when try to run node.js application.
I would like to uninstall NVM and  remove all installed Node.js versions.
How do i completely remove it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can remove `$NVM_DIR` which is usually `~/.nvm`.

```bash
rm -rf $NVM_DIR
```

There will also be a snippet in your terminal profile file (i.e. `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`) which you can remove. The snippet safely loads NVM, so if it's not installed then nothing will happen.

It'll look something like

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Afterwards you will need to restart your terminal to not have a lingering `node` alias.